# Force capitalization in iOS web page?

Tags: ios, web, safari, webkit

This should be easy to fix, but I can't find out why it's not working.

I have a web "app" that runs in Safari, and it's made for users to add to the home screen.  There's a web form where the user enters a first and last name.  Here's the simple code for that form.

```
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="pFirstName" value="" autocapitalize="on" autocorrect="off" placeholder="John" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="pLastName" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on" placeholder="Doe" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Very simple.  The problem is that the Last Name form is not capitalized when the user switches to it.  I ran it directly in mobile Safari, and it worked fine.  When I added to the home screen, I had the same issue...

Is this just a bug in iOS/webkit (because it used to work...)?  Not sure if there's some sort of script to force the auto-capitalization?  Thanks!

*Edit: If I click on the field directly, it capitalizes. The problem is when I fill in text for first name, and click the "Next" arrow on the top of the keyboard.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using autocapitalize="sentences"

Comment: Didn't work, but it did help me find something else.  If I click on the field directly, it capitalizes.  The problem is when I fill in text for first name, and click the "Next" arrow on the top of the keyboard.